# Accessing Core Data Child Objects in Nested SwiftUI List

Tags: core-data, swiftui

My end goal is to create a SwiftUI `List` with children. I have sections (parent) that contain projects (children), and the sections will expand and collapse their list of projects.

I have this built with an `NSOutlineView` using Realm, but now I'm trying to build it with SwiftUI and Core Data. `*GULP*` : )

[image]

I'm not very experienced with Core Data, but I think I have my data set up right. I have a `Section` entity and a `Project` entity, and the `Section` has a `projects` attribute that has a to-many relationship.

[image]

So, I presume (incorrectly as shown below) `section.projects` is a collection of `Project` objects.

For simplicity, I'm just trying to nest to the two inside a `List` (I'll worry about the `DisclosureGroup` stuff later):

```
List{
  ForEach(sections, id: \.recordName){ section in
    Text(section.name)
    ForEach(section.projects, id: \.recordName){ project in //<-- ERROR
      Text(project.name)
    }
  }
}
```

The line marked above has two errors that seems to suggest I don't have an array of objects to work with in `section.projects`:

> *Referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'NSObject' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'*

> *Value of optional type 'NSOrderedSet?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'NSOrderedSet'*

If `section.projects` is an `NSOrderedSet`, why can't I iterate over it?

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out with the help of this article: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/one-to-many-relationships-with-core-data-swiftui-and-fetchrequest

I had to change my Core Data entities to have their **Codegen** setting be `Manual/None` (in the `.xcdatamodeld` editor in Xcode). I then select my entities and go to **Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass...** which created a bunch of files that reflect my Core Data models.

Then inside the **Section+CoreDataProperties.swift** file, I added a computed property to give me access to my projects (sorted by name):

```
public var projectArray: [Project] {
  let set = projects as? Set<Project> ?? []
  return set.sorted {
    $0.wrappedName < $1.wrappedName
  }
}
```

And then, for convenience, inside **Project+CoreDataProperties.swift** I added this:

```
public var wrappedName: String{
  name ?? "Unknown Name"
}
```

...which allows my computed property to sort my projects by name (since Core Data treats strings as optionals by default).

As a result, I was able to iterate over my nested data like this:

```
ForEach(sections, id: \.self) { section in
  Text(section.wrappedName)
        
  ForEach(section.projectArray, id: \.self) { project in
    Text(project.wrappedName)
  }
}
```

Comment: Clifton worth mentioning perhaps and as an aside, for simplicity you might like to use `Codegen = Class Definition`and instead of manually preparing your `NSManagedObject` subclasses, write an extension for each Core Data entity that you require computed properties for (e.g. `extension Project { ... }` for your `wrappedName` computed `var`).